# Get all XML elements with the same name

Tags: c#, xml

I have an `XML` like this:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Account diffgr:id="Account 1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <ID>11</ID>
            <Name>Hello</Name>
            <Description>Good Boy</Description>
        </Account>
        <Account diffgr:id="Account 2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
            <ID>12</ID>
            <Name>Nop</Name>
            <Description>Bad Boy</Description>
        </Account>      
        <Collections diffgr:id="Collection 33" msdata:rowOrder="62">
            <ID>1233</ID>
            <Name>Wrist Watches</Name>
            <Value>Expensive</Value>
            <IsArchieved>false</IsArchieved>
        </Collections>      
    </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

The names come at run-time but by the time I get to this part of the code I know the node names so I do have a list of them like this:

```
List<string> nodeNames = new List<string>{"Account", "Collections"}
```

Now I want to get a list of all the things for each each nodeName which is the part of code I don't know why it is not working. (I have classes to deserialize it later).

So I want all of these in one Enumerable for **"Account"**:

```
<Account diffgr:id="Account 1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <ID>11</ID>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Description>Good Boy</Description>
</Account>
<Account diffgr:id="Account 2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <ID>12</ID>
    <Name>Nop</Name>
    <Description>Bad Boy</Description>
</Account>
```

and similarly I want all of these in one Enumerable for "**Collections**":

```
<Collections diffgr:id="Collection 33" msdata:rowOrder="62">
    <ID>1233</ID>
    <Name>Wrist Watches</Name>
    <Value>Expensive</Value>
    <IsArchieved>false</IsArchieved>
</Collections>
```

**And I have done it like this:**

```
var n = nodeNames.Select(n => myXMLData.Descendants(XName.Get(n, "")));
```

The problem is when I look at the result, **they are all empty.**
Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

The answer is following the same [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata'
                 xmlns:diffgr='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1'>
            <NewDataSet xmlns=''>
                <Account diffgr:id='Account 1' msdata:rowOrder='0'>
                    <ID>11</ID>
                    <Name>Hello</Name>
                    <Description>Good Boy</Description>
                </Account>
                <Account diffgr:id='Account 2' msdata:rowOrder='1'>
                    <ID>12</ID>
                    <Name>Nop</Name>
                    <Description>Bad Boy</Description>
                </Account>
                <Collections diffgr:id='Collection 33' msdata:rowOrder='62'>
                    <ID>1233</ID>
                    <Name>Wrist Watches</Name>
                    <Value>Expensive</Value>
                    <IsArchieved>false</IsArchieved>
                </Collections>
            </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>");
        
    IEnumerable<XElement> collection1 = xdoc.Descendants("Account");
    Console.WriteLine(collection1);

    IEnumerable<XElement> collection2 = xdoc.Descendants("Collections");
    Console.WriteLine(collection2);
}
```

**Output**

```
<Account diffgr:id="Account 1" msdata:rowOrder="0" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <ID>11</ID>
  <Name>Hello</Name>
  <Description>Good Boy</Description>
</Account>
<Account diffgr:id="Account 2" msdata:rowOrder="1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Name>Nop</Name>
  <Description>Bad Boy</Description>
</Account>


<Collections diffgr:id="Collection 33" msdata:rowOrder="62" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <ID>1233</ID>
  <Name>Wrist Watches</Name>
  <Value>Expensive</Value>
  <IsArchieved>false</IsArchieved>
</Collections>
```